# int support in ChannelBuffer

Tags: netty

Writing a DownstreamHandler and I need to encode an int to a ChannelBuffer.

ChannelBuffers.copiedBuffer(...) has a method which converts a string into a buffer.

How do I convert an int to a ChannelBuffer?

Answer (score 1):

Got a solution to this myself:

```
final ChannelBuffer myIntBuffer = channel.getConfig().getBufferFactory().getBuffer(4);

myIntBuffer.writeInt(myInt);
```

Hopefully it is the best/correct approach.

Comment: You are correct. There is a feature request: https://github.com/netty/netty/issues/167